# Does AWS have Windows 10 AMI available?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ami

Does AWS have Windows 10 AMI available? I can only find Windows Server AMIs

At this link I can only see Windows Server AMIs

https://aws.amazon.com/windows/resources/amis/

Comment: see my response below

Answer (score 9):

You can use [AWS Import/Export](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSImportExport/latest/DG/whatisdisk.html) to transfer existing disk images into AWS, [**including Windows 10**](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/vm-import/latest/userguide/vmie_prereqs.html).

However, you will be responsible for the licensing of non-Server products such as Windows 10.

Answer (score 6):

AWS Workspaces does not give you a Windows client install. AWS will only provide server installs.

*"All Amazon WorkSpaces bundles include a Microsoft Windows 7 or Windows 10 desktop experience, powered by Windows Server 2008 R2 and Windows Server 2016 respectively..."*.

As per [aws.amazon.com/workspaces/details](https://aws.amazon.com/workspaces/details/)

I tested this and even though "Standard with Windows 10 Free tier eligible" was selected, I logged in to a Server 2016 system.

Answer (score 4):

I believe AWS only provide Windows Server AMIs, though Windows Server 2016 is the server equivalent platform to Windows 10. They likely only have licenses to run Windows Server.

You can run Windows 10 on Amazon WorkSpaces, but you need to purchase your own license for this.

Edit: Looks like AWS now provide licensed copies of Windows 10 through WorkSpaces. Thanks Matt Houser!

Comment: Licenses are now included in the price for the Windows 10 WorkSpaces.

Comment: Ah awesome! I missed that!

Comment: Not Windows 10.   Server 2016 with Desktop Experience.   No Windows Store and no Edge browser.

Answer (score 3):

Amazon offers Amazon Workspaces where you can get Windows 10 (even within Free-tier) - link https://docs.aws.amazon.com/workspaces/latest/adminguide/getting-started.html

As of time of writing the post - there is no AMIs for Windows 10 you could deploy on EC2 instances if this is what you were trying to do.

Here are options as of 28 March 2018 for Amazon Workspaces:

- Standard with Windows 7 **Free tier eligible** 2 vCPU 4 GiB 50 GB
- Standard with Windows 10 **Free tier eligible** 2 vCPU 4 GiB 50 GB
- Standard with Windows 7 and Office 2010 2 vCPU 4 GiB 50 GB
- Standard with Windows 7 and Office 2013 2 vCPU 4 GiB 50 GB
- Standard with Windows 10 and Office 2016 2 vCPU 4 GiB 50 GB
- Value with Windows 7 1 vCPU 2 GiB 10 GB
- Value with Windows 10 1 vCPU 2 GiB 10 GB
- Value with Windows 7 and Office 2010 1 vCPU 2 GiB 10 GB
- Value with Windows 7 and Office 2013 1 vCPU 2 GiB 10 GB
- Value with Windows 10 and Office 2016 1 vCPU 2 GiB 10 GB
- Performance with Windows 7 2 vCPU 7.5 GiB 100 GB
- Performance with Windows 10 2 vCPU 7.5 GiB 100 GB
- Performance with Windows 7 and Office 2010 2 vCPU 7.5 GiB 100 GB
- Performance with Windows 7 and Office 2013 2 vCPU 7.5 GiB 100 GB
- Performance with Windows 10 and Office 2016 2 vCPU 7.5 GiB 100 GB
- Graphics with Windows 7 8 vCPU 15 GiB 100 GB
- Graphics with Windows 10 8 vCPU 15 GiB 100 GB
- Graphics with Windows 7 and Office 2010 8 vCPU 15 GiB 100 GB
- Graphics with Windows 7 and Office 2013 8 vCPU 15 GiB 100 GB
- Graphics with Windows 10 and Office 2016 8 vCPU 15 GiB 100 GB
- Power with Windows 74 vCPU 16 GiB 100 GB
- Power with Windows 7 and Office 2013 4 vCPU 16 GiB 100 GB
- Power with Windows 10 4 vCPU 16 GiB 100 GB
- Power with Windows 10 and Office 2016 4 vCPU 16 GiB 100 GB

Comment: Not Windows 10.   Server 2016 with Desktop Experience.   No Windows Store and no Edge browser.

Comment: @Wpigott : "Windows 10 desktop experience, powered by Windows Server 2008 R2 and Windows Server 2016" - https://aws.amazon.com/workspaces/details/#Amazon_WorkSpaces_Bundles

Comment: Yes.  I am writing this from an AWS Workspace.   It is Server 2016 with Windows 10 experience.  It is NOT Windows 10.   As I said before, it is missing the Windows Store and the Edge browser.

Comment: Quite expensive!

Answer (score 0):

Try this new AMI.

https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/prodview-6izpqsustac6a

It is a safe and reliable Windows Desktop capable of running in a virtualized environment. I should know, I built it. It is newly available on Amazon.  Subscribe and make AMI copies while it is still available.

If the Administrator password is not set on first launch, reboot the instance via console and wait until fully up before trying to log in again.

If all else fails, SSH log in using your public/private key pair used at launch and set password via PowerShell:

```
$Password = ConvertTo-SecureString "MyNewPassword" -AsPlainText -Force
Get-LocalUser -Name "Administrator" | Set-LocalUser -Password $Password
```

Then, remove the cloud init script to prevent it from resetting your password to the instance ID:

```
unregister-scheduledtask -TaskName TLC-init
```

Comment: No longer available unfortunately